# How can I disable the color formatting of the URL bar in Firefox 6?

Tags: firefox

[image]

Firefox highlights the name of the site I am currently on. I very often need to read various IDs and/or other params from the URL, so I don't need the focus on the site name.

How can I have the old one back, where everything is black?

Comment: The point of this highlighting is that many users do *not* know what site they are on. Think `http://gmail.com.ServiceLogin.lulz.com/`... The average Firefox user does not *need* to care about URL parameters.

Comment: so? I only use FF because it is so flexible and extensible. If FF is not going to support advanced users, why should I use this memory-hog at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got to `about:config` and change `browser.urlbar.formatting.enabled` to `false`.

Comment: This was a huge help, I need to read the url when doing web development and the new changes made this extremely difficult, even with a huge monitor it was still very difficult to read. Light grey text on a white background is just way too little contrast, they could have picked any other number of ways to highlight the domain, this was not a great choice IMO.

Comment: In current version (I have 91.6.0esr) this preference isn't listed any longer. Simply add it and the formatting is gone.