# How to enable URL formatting in Firefox 5 Omnibar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I was reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/323965/how-can-i-disable-the-color-formatting-of-the-url-bar-in-firefox-6) about turning off URL formatting in Firefox's URL bar. That was the first time I heard of the feature so I went to `about:config` to turn it on and couldn't find it.

Since the questioner made it sound like it was turned on by default, I'm guessing I don't see it because I have omnibar and did since several updates ago. Is there a way to enable it anyway, perhaps by adding a variable to `about:config`?

Relevant system info:

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Firefox 5.0
- GNOME 2.30.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is new in Firefox 6.  (The question you linked does specify that version.)

EDIT: As grawity helpfully points out, if for some reason you don't want to upgrade to 6.0, there is always An Extension For That.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that caveat. I didn't want to upgrade to 6 because I run Ubuntu and I find that it's better for my plugins and my peace of mind if I leave firefox to the update manager. And yes, there is *always* An Extension For That.

Comment: @Yitzchak - FWIW, 6.0 officially came out of beta today, so you'll probably see that update come down the pipe soon.

Comment: @Shinrai: In Ubuntu, "soon" may take quite a while (perhaps not until 11.10...)

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox 5, you need to install the [Locationbar²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locationbar%C2%B2/) extension.